# Sort columns automatically

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database-table with some football-matches, 3 per week, and I wrote them in a table like this example:

```
week  |team1   |team2   |date1   |time1   |team3  |team4  |date2  |time2  |
46    |Chelsea |Man Utd |18/11   |13:30   |Arsenal|Stoke  |19/11  |18:00  |
```

Then I have this code to call them:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE week = '$week'";
```

...where `$week = Date('W');`

```
echo $row['team1'].' - '.$row['team2'].'<br />
'.$row['team3'].' - '.$row['team4'].';
```

and so on. But sometimes the date or time changes, so I have to make the whole row again, because else it will still show the first match first, even though the other match will be played first. Let say Chelea - Man Utd is moved to the 20/11 at 18:00. Can I somehow just change the date and time in the row and make the matches rearrange on the front-end?

Sorry if it's a bit difficult to understand what I'm talking about :)

Comment: Bad database/table schema. Use table structure like `week | team1_id | team2_id | date | time`, then changes are easy. Indexing columns is the best way to hell. `Team_id` instead of `team name` is better when you will need change the team name in future.

Comment: That is a bad database design. You should only have one datetime field, and store a second football match in a separate row. Also the week number can be derived from the date, so is essential duplicate information. Write a view to calculate the week number on the fly, but don't store it.

Comment: I know it would be easier to store on match in one row. The problem is, that my users should be able to bet on the matches and if I have them in one row, I'm not sure how to make sure they are betting on the right match week after week?

Comment: That is a display issue, not a database design issue. You can query in such a way that you find records that belong to the same week, if that is the issue.

Comment: @trincot Not sure I understand. If fx I have 3 matches in 3 different rows, all with the week number 46, I know how to "order" them, but then I'm not sure how to make sure they are betting on the right match. But I see that's another question, so maybe I should delete this one and try out the other design :)

Comment: I don't understand why there is a concern of betting on the right match. Naively I would think you would present the list of matches the users can bet on, and then you register what they choose to bet on.

Comment: Yes, I have another table where I store the bets, but they are stored with `result1`, `result2`, and so on. And then the points are given by a case-string, so when I fx write the result 2-1 everyone who had 2-1 in that week get points. But if I give every match their own row, I can't call it `result1` but only `result`. And then I don't know how to connect the users bet with the right match. Oh, I really don't know how to explain it properply. So sorry!

Comment: @trincot I guess what I'm trying to say is, that I'll end up with 3 rows all with the week 46, but how do I give them some kind of unique id? The site is automatically choosing the 3 matches every week, so I need some kind of id. Right now it chooses the row with fx week 46 and all 3 matches are in the same row and have an id (`result1`, `result2`...) so in the php, when the user say 2-1 in the first game, it writes 2-1 in `result1` in the table.

Comment: You can just let the database generate a unique id for each row and reference that in the bet. The actual date/time and teams will not be stored in the bets table; they will be retrieved via the `id` from the main matches table.

Comment: @trincot Yea, but then I have to enter the php-script every week to change the `id` for each match.

Comment: No, you would have to *select* the `id` values from the matches table based on the date range of your interest (something like `select id from matches where datetime between '2017-11-12' and '2017-11-18 23:59'`).

Answer (score 1):

First, I think your tables has not correctly formatted, you shouldn't have fields like `field1`, `field2`, `field3`... If you require that : you should be create another table :D Like that: Or you have a logical problem. I think an architecture like that is better addapted to your database :

```
# table team
id  | name
1   | Chelsea
2   | Man Utd 
3   | Arsenal
4   | Stoke
```

If a team change this name, is more efficient, if value is once in other table.

```
# table match
id  | local_team_id | external_team_id | dateTime             | week | score ^_^
1   | 1             | 2                | 2017-11-14 19:30:06  | 46   | 2-0
2   | 3             | 4                | 2017-11-15 18:30:21  | 46   | 2-0
```

Also, if possible, never use the `SELECT * FROM your_table` is not effective, and very not good for performance. You must just return in your request the values you need in your PHP. Not more.

From your sample you can write:

```
"SELECT team1, team2, team3, team4 FROM table_name WHERE week='$week'"
```

But, even with that, you can have a problem of [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). You can fix it with PHP method, or with using PDO and [prepare query](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.prepare.php). A sample of your request with PDO :

```
$query = "SELECT team1, team2, team3, team4 FROM table_name WHERE week= :week"
$dbh->prepare($query, , array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$dbh->execute([':week' => $week]);
```

So, for answer to your question, you can order the result column, with define fields in your request :

```
SELECT first, second, third FROM table_name
```

And you can order the rows results with the `ORDER BY` clause (see the doc [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) ) like that :

```
SELECT team1, team2, team3, team4, week FROM table_name ORDER_BY week DESC
```

Hope I help you.

Comment: Thank you! That was a lot of info so I think it's going to take some time for me because I'm pretty new at this :) But thank you - I'll give this a shot :)

Comment: You're welcome :) That lot of informations, but it's good practise your learn with time ;) Performance, maintainability and security has required for all web projects. Good Luck for improve your code :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are asking about how to redesign or query an existing data structure, please include the definition of the data structure (in your case, the CREATE TABLE statement) as well as examples of the data it contains.

The title of your question talks about sorting - but the body of your question is about how the date/time of a match changes. If you want to control the order in which rows are retrieved from an SQL DBMS, then SQL has a solution for that - specify a [ORDER BY clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html) in your SELECT statement.

But I suspect that your problem is the fact that you are putting details of multiple matches into a single row in your table. This is very wrong.

A table describing matches should only contain one match per row. Arguably, it shouldn't contain teams either (since both teams have the same physical relationship to a match, using different columns to hold them creates an artificial difference) but this is probably overkill for most purposes.

I would implement this as:

```
  CREATE TABLE match (
    ondate DATETIME,
    home_team VARCHAR(20),
    away_team VARCHAR(20)
    PRIMARY KEY (ondate, home_team)
  );
```

(it may require other indices depending on usage).

I am assuming that the week can be derived from the datetime (e.g.if a match scheduled for week 40 is postponed by 7 days, it is then considered to be in week 41).

If you want to *display* all the matches occurring in one week as a row at the front end then, although its possible to format the data this way in the output of a SELECT statement, you should handle this in your PHP code.

Comment: But still, when there's 3 matches a week each match would need some kind of unique id besides the date. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to make sure the bets are connected to the right match, right?

Comment: In my example above it *has* a unique ID - ondate and hometeam. I wrote this before you posted the comment about bets. If you have relevant contraints applicable to a problem YOU SHOULD STATE THEM IN YOUR QUESTION. Whether that is still appropriate as a primary key / sufficient as a foreign key in your table of bets is a different question but this is getting too broad for a discussion on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Wow, sorry, wouldn't want to upset you. I just had a problem and want to learn how to do it. But okay, I'll just close this question. Don't want to make anyone mad just because I'm not as good as them at coding. Have a nice day.